# Would bypass of the controller in CodeIgniter be considered a good practice?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is directly call to the Model class inside the View is best practice or not? Currently I am using CodeIgniter to develop an application. In different Views of my application I'm including menus that I want to pull from the database. And the thing is currently I am passing the values to the menu through the controller. If I make a common model class and call it from the View and by pass controller. So that there will be one call to Model and it will load menu from the database at once and by pass the controller. By doing this what pros and cons will come?

Comment: Have you tried to call a model in view..??

Comment: Yes I make a test case to invoke the conroller in the view and I can. I know all MVC logic stuff (I don't need explanation to that). You people didn't get my question. The thing is there are too many views in my app and in every view i am including top menu and in every case the controler is quering to a database and pull the top menu. If I will by pass the controller than the top menu which will query once to the database and save the too many calls to the databse on every view open. I just need a sincere opinion by doing this is OK or I will not do that, must use Controller and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With codeigniter, your views should not be concerned as to where data comes from, only that it exists.  Only your Controllers should be in direct contact with your Models.

It sounds like you have a common menu that you want to load in your views and you don't want to replicate that code across all your Controllers.

To solve this problem, you need to create a common controller that your primary controllers inherit from with a method that fetches the menu.

`My_Controller` needs to be saved to the `core` folder in the `application` directory.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    protected function get_menu()
    {
        // Load your menu here
        $this->load->model('menu_model');
        return $this->menu_model->get_menu();
    }
}
```

All your primary controllers will inherit `MY_Controller`

```
class Home_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $page_data = array('menu' => $this->get_menu());
        $this->load->view('home/index', $page_data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion no its not best practice. View should contact Controller and Controllers should retrieve data from Model where Model does all the logic. Controller suppose to be the glue or middleman of View and Model.

Controller passes the returned data into View and then you do your foreach loop or whatever to display it.

View should not be doing any logic. Retrieving data from database is somewhat logic.

Answer (score 0):

It is a worst practise. Then why we have controller concept for MVC. :) Mainly all logics goes into Model so thats not good to call model directly.

Answer (score -1):

There will not be any problem, since you are using a common controller.

Note : You should not call model directly from view.

Comment: Actually I'm proper MVC implementation (not that crap-for-joke that is CodeIgniter) the view instances are responsible for acquiring information from **model layer**. This information then is used by current view to decide which templates to use to create the response. **View is not a template.**

Comment: Agreed. But View should not do any Logical operations, controller should do.